# Can I read a string and then use it as an integer?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert string to int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

MY code is supposed to read strings and then take the corresponding actions, but if that string is a line of numbers i need this line as a full number (an int) not as a string anymore.can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Integer.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(someString);
```

(There are other options as well.)

Comment: yup,that will do.
Thanks

Comment: This will work, but has unnecessary boxing and unboxing.  Better to use `Integer.parseInt(...)` for primitive `int`.

Comment: yep. As per the documentation, valueOf returns an **Integer Object** whereas parseInt returns a **primitive int** and that's what you want. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: It wasn't clear to me since the title said "integer" (but lower-case) and the text said "int". I find it unlikely the boxing is going to cause the OP timing issues.

Comment: It might not be a problem for the OP but it might be a problem for a future answer seeking coder. It should at least be mentioned when proposing the `valueOf` method.

Comment: @wullxz It's mentioned explicitly in the linked documentation; IMO that's enough--feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I will try both valueOf and Integer.parseInt. anyway thanks everyone

Comment: @AngeloMico They'll both work, they do the same thing (in their simplest form)--the comments regarding the autoboxing are correct; if you need your code to be as fast as possible, or truly need an `int`, `parseInt` is a better choice. I tend to stick to objects because I don't do a lot of numerically-intensive work in Java.

Comment: nah i don't really care to make my code faster,just need something that works,I'm new to java so my supervisor doesn't want anything else other than a correct code

Answer (score 3):

Look at the static method `Integer.parseInt(String string)`. This method is overloaded and is also capable of reading values in other numeral systems than the decimal system. If `string`can't be parsed as Integer, the method throws a `NumberFormatException` which can be catched as follows:

```
string = "1234"
try {
   int i = Integer.parseInt(string);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   System.err.println(string + " is not a number!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what **Dave** and **wullxz** said, you could also user regular expressions to find out if tested string matches your format e.g.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...

String value = "23423423";

if(Pattern.matches("^\\d+$", value)) {
   return Integer.valueOf(value);
}
```

Using regular expression you could also recover other type of numbers like doubles e.g.

```
String value = "23423423.33";
if(Pattern.matches("^\\d+$", value)) {
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(value));
}
else if(Pattern.matches("^\\d+\\.\\d+$", value)) {
    System.out.println(Double.valueOf(value));
}
```

I hope that will help to solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Also, as suggested by **wullxz**, you could use `Integer.parseInt(String)` instead of `Integer.valueOf(String)`. `parseInt` returns `int` whereas `valueOf` returns `Integer` instance. From performance point of view `parseInt` is recommended.

Comment: I'd suggest you to change your use of `valueOf` to `parseInt` respectively `parseDouble`. (see the comments under **Dave**'s answer)

Comment: @wullxz very good; from performance point of view that method is recommended (+1).